# Place Autocomplete API returns predictions with incorrect matched_substrings

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I am making the following query (`key` param omitted):

```
curl -v 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Helloo&types=geocode'
```

In the results I get, the first prediction is:

```
  {
     "description" : "Clinton, New York, NY, United States",
     "id" : "e5c6298aafa5b208354b16aecd163ac85eda40ae",
     "matched_substrings" : [
        {
           "length" : 7,
           "offset" : 0
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJUWBgpFBYwokRAprvYGCydhk",
     "reference" : "CkQ8AAAAKW4NgbXbTCXL8MuOOUohazn6TzvRlt8eurqW4QPFCMQXDZDP7nUQXT3c2rb4BYTcIc6fdZH2sQOj-MdNifcsZhIQFK85n69ce3b1Ec93MNxpBBoU4O778Tm2b8-tHTyCiUAZmh00QBI",
     "structured_formatting" : {
        "main_text" : "Clinton",
        "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
           {
              "length" : 7,
              "offset" : 0
           }
        ],
        "secondary_text" : "New York, NY, United States"
     },
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "Clinton"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 9,
           "value" : "New York"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 19,
           "value" : "NY"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 23,
           "value" : "United States"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political", "geocode" ]
  },
```

You'll notice "Clinton" does not appear in my input string. Where is this result coming from? Why am I getting it? [The docs say](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) that `matched_subtrings`

> contains an array with offset value and length. These describe the location of the entered term in the prediction result text, so that the term can be highlighted if desired.

which is clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed something up, your request does not actually return those predictions, it returns 2 geocodes that match your input:

```
"predictions" : [
   {
      "description" : "Helloo Creek, Halls Creek, New South Wales, Australia",
      "matched_substrings" : [
         {
            "length" : 6,
            "offset" : 0
         }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJWVba98sSoGsRZDAiQHlxv6I",
      ...
  },
  {
      "description" : "Helloop, Achtmaal, Netherlands",
      "id" : "5f9eb5caffb95c218e8c9ef002aabf7ae85d597e",
      "matched_substrings" : [
         {
            "length" : 6,
            "offset" : 0
         }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJQdEGANsaxEcRUJeH7LZlmBk",
      ...
```

If you ever have a similar problem again, please file a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789006).

Comment: Thanks for attempting to reproduce. I didn't mess anything up: the above URL is identical to my original request (except it excludes my `key`), and the response is what I pasted in my question. I now get the same response as you. So looks like it's been fixed. Thanks for the issue tracker link.